# body properties, except an element

Tags: css

```
body{ line-height: 1;  // others }
```

Yes I want to obtain line-height for body tag. But a div expect in this tag. You will say, "define a class for this div and change the line-height whatever you want". I want to change this value to native value. Like no css. Like restore the default browser's values.

Comment: "But a div expect in this tag"??

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for. But, if you set the `line-height` on `body`, any child `div` elements will by default inherit that `line-height`.

Comment: I want to set on body. But a div in body mustn't inherit this property.

Comment: The `div`s will inherit the properties set on `body`. There's nothing you can do prevent this. To workaround this, you must do `div { /* reset the required properties here */ }`. It would be sensible to simply do `div { line-height: 1.25 }` (or whatever value) - that way, you know the `line-height` will be consistent between different browsers, no matter what the browser default is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default value: `{ line-height: normal; }`

you can try:

by id:

```
body *:not(#mydiv_id) {
 line-height: 1;  // others }
}
```

by class:

```
body *:not(.mydiv_class) {
 line-height: 1;  // others }
}
```

by type:

```
body *:not(div) {
 line-height: 1;  // others }
}
```

**N.B.:**

The negation pseudo-class, `:not()` is not supported on IE8 and lower.

Comment: What about others? Can you type here all of their default values?

Comment: what others? all css properties?

Comment: :) of course not. I try to say Is there any selector or way, whatever, doing this? " except #mydiv line-height: 1; " This would be very useful

Comment: You should mention the unfortunate downside of `not()` - that it doesn't work in IE8 and lower :(

Comment: wasn't aware of that, I'll mention it.

Answer (score 1):

For most properties, you can just set it to `auto` or `inherit`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)?

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to
>   reduce browser inconsistencies in
>   things like default line heights,
>   margins and font sizes of headings,
>   and so on.

Or, are you asking how to set individual properties back to the "default value"?

[Find the property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height), and look for the *"Initial value"*; in this case, it's `line-height: normal`.